# How do I get italic type using baskervald font?

Tags: fonts, header-footer, italic

I have loaded the font here:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        
\usepackage[light]{iwona}
\usepackage{baskervald}
```

I am trying to set some type in a `fancy` header in *italics*:

```
\fancyhead[L]{\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont \Large{\textcolor{AFRed}{\{ analysis first \}}}\\
                          \fontfamily{baskervald}\selectfont  \scriptsize{\textcolor{AFBlack}{\ \ \ \ \ solutions through science}}}}
```

I have tried `\textit{}` and `\itshape`, but have had no luck. Any suggestions?

new comment on question:

Here is the entire preamble of my document (other than how I set the title page). This reflects some suggestions from cfr.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry} % to override default page geometry

\usepackage{graphics} % needed to insert graphics other than PS

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\graphicspath{{graphics/}} % where to look for graphics files

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to manipulate what goes in the page header and footer

\usepackage{color} % color in the document, other than graphics

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % put text at a precise position on the page

\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc} % multiple foot styles

\usepackage{lipsum} % generate random text for demonstration

\setlength{\topmargin}{-1cm}

\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}

\setlength{\headsep}{1cm} % defining the separation between the header and the main body

\setlength{\textheight}{21.2cm} % total height of text in main body

\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} % total width of text in main body

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm} % this defines the units use in the text block command

\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}

\newcommand{\cth}{\small CTH~} % command to typeset computer code CTH in smaller font

\newcommand{\cale}{\small CALE~} % command to typeset computer code CALE in smaller font

\newcommand{\theAFTitle}{} % define the \theAFTitle command

\newcommand{\theclient}{} % define the \theclient command

\newcommand{\theReportDate}{} % define the \theReportDate command

\newcommand{\thedisclaimer}{} % define the \thedisclaimer command

\newcommand{\theTechnical}{} % define the \theTechnical command

\newcommand{\theBusiness}{} % define the \theBusiness command


\newcommand{\AFTitle}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theAFTitle}{#1}
}                                   

\newcommand{\client}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theclient}{#1}
}                                   

\newcommand{\ReportDate}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theReportDate}{#1}
}                                   

\newcommand{\disclaimer}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thedisclaimer}{#1}
}                                   

\newcommand{\Technical}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theTechnical}{#1}
}                                   

\newcommand{\Business}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theBusiness}{#1}
}                                   

\definecolor{AFRed}{RGB}{102,0,0}

\definecolor{AFBlack}{RGB}{63,63,63}

\fancypagestyle{fancyAF}{%

    \fancyhf{}

    \newsavebox{\AFHead}

    \newlength{\AFHeadwidth}

    \settowidth{\AFHeadwidth}{\fontfamily{iwona} \selectfont

                \Large{\textcolor{AFRed}{\{ analysis first \}}}}

    \sbox{\AFHead}{%

        \parbox{\AFHeadwidth}{

            \center

            \fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont \Large{\textcolor{AFRed}{\{ analysis first \}}} \\

            \fontfamily{baskervald}\selectfont \itshape \scriptsize{\textcolor{AFBlack}{solultions through science}}}

    }
    \fancyhead[L]{\usebox{\AFHead}}

    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%

    \clearpage

    \pagestyle{fancyAF}

    \mbox{}

    \begin{textblock}{5.5}(1.1667,2.0)

        \noindent{\textsf{\bf{\LARGE{\theAFTitle}}}}

    \end{textblock}

    \begin{textblock}{7}(1.1667,3.25)

        \noindent{\textsf{\Large{Analysis First \\ 48 Webster Circle \\ Granville, OH  43023}}}

    \end{textblock}

    \begin{textblock}{7}(1.1667,4.25)

        \noindent{\textsf{\Large{To: \\ \theclient}}}

    \end{textblock}

    \begin{textblock}{2}(1.1667,5.0)

        \noindent{\textsf{\large{\theReportDate}}}

    \end{textblock}

    \begin{textblock}{2}(1.1667,5.5)

        \noindent{\textsf{\bf Technical Contact:} \\ \theTechnical}

    \end{textblock}

%   \begin{textblock}{2}(4.0,5.5)

%        \noindent{\textsf{\bf Management Contact:} \\ \theBusiness}

%    \end{textblock}

    \begin{textblock}{5.5}(0.8333,6.5)

        \noindent{\thedisclaimer}

    \end{textblock}

    \newpage

}



\begin{document}

\AFTitle{White Paper}

\client{XYZ Corporation}

\ReportDate{December 2013}

\Technical{Dr. Michael Fisher \\ Director \\ (740) 587-0506 \\ fisher@analysisfirst.org}

\Business{}

\disclaimer{This proposal or quotation includes data that shall not be disclosed outside the government and shall not be duplicated, used, or disclosed-in whole or in part-for any purpose other than to evaluate this proposal or quotation.  If, however, a contract is awarded to this offeror or quoter as a result of-or in connection with-the submission of this data, the government shall have the right to duplicate, use, or disclose the data to the extent provided in the resulting contract.  This restriction does not limit the government's right to use information contained in this data if it is obtained from another source without restriction.  The data subject to this restriction are contained in all pages of this proposal.}

\maketitle

\section{Background}

\lipsum

\section{Objective}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Technical}

\lipsum[10-20]

\section{Key Personnel, Program Schedule, and ROM Costs}

\lipsum[1-2]



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please complete your code to form a document people can compile to reproduce the issue. Also, what exactly is meant to be in italics? That code changes fonts and size but not shape so it is not clear what is supposed to be italic and what not.

Comment: I want the second line of the fancy header to be in italic, i.e., solutions through science.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You cannot use `\fontfamily{baskervald}` to switch to Baskervald because that is the the name of the font family.

Answer (score 2):

The name of a font family is not generally the name of the font. That means that you cannot put the name of the font into a `\fontfamily{}` command and expect it to work. If you look at the output, you will see complaints from LaTeX when if fails to find the font you have requested.

I'm not sure about the overall structure of your document but you really ought not define the header in that way. For example, forcing spaces using `\ \` is not a good way to do it.

What you've shown in your preamble is also problematic. The line loading `iwona` is not really doing anything because the `baskervald` package overwrites the changes `iwona` makes to the font configuration. That is, first `iwona` sets up the default roman family as Iwona in the light weight. Then `baskervald` sets up the default roman family as non-swash Baskervald. So you could not load `iwona` and get essentially the same result.

Note, too, that using two serif fonts in the same document is generally typographically abhorrent, and ought to be avoided unless you really know what you are doing. (I think it can be a little different if you are using something like Zapf Chancery for fancy headings because it does not exactly look like 'another serif' as it is so different. But that's not the case for Iwona and Baskervald.)

However, this site does not enforce typographic taste. Hence, it is admissible for the purposes of TeX SE to describe a technical solution to a design specification, regardless of aesthetic considerations. While I absolutely recommend not using this, therefore, here is how you might do it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=26pt]{geometry}% LaTeX reports that the headheight must be at least 25.something pt to accommodate the header
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}% don't load iwona as well as it is not doing anything
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% just for testing
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\begin{document}
  % set up the header after the start of the document so we get the right fonts and stuff automatically
  \newsavebox{\frightfulhead}
  \newlength{\frightfulwidth}
  \settowidth{\frightfulwidth}{\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont\Large\{ analysis first \}}% measure the required width
  \sbox{\frightfulhead}{% put the contents of the header in a box
    \parbox{\frightfulwidth}{% multiple lines so we'll use a \parbox with the width measured above
      \raggedleft% set everything flush right
      {\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont\Large {\{ analysis first \}}\\}% the curly brackets limit the scope of the font selection command
      \itshape solutions through science}}% so this line returns to the default family i.e. baskervald
  \fancyhead[L]{\usebox{\frightfulhead}}% install the header

  \kant[1-2]% dummy text
\end{document}
```

[image: frightful header - not recommended at all!]

## Update

If you do not want *either* Iwona *or* Baskervald as the default serif, the best strategy is not to load either `iwona` or `baskervald` but to select the fonts directly. However, you need to use the correct family names so we need to figure out what the correct family names are.

For Baskervald, page 3 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/baskervaldadf/doc/fonts/baskervald/baskervaldadf.pdf) explains that two font families are defined, `ybv` and `ybvw`. Page 6 tells us that the former is the standard, non-swash family. So that's the font family we want to select. The documentation also tells us that we need the `T1` encoding as this is what the package supports.

For Iwona, the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/iwona/00readme.eng) gives tells us which encodings are available (`T1` seems a good choice again) but it is less clear what the name of the font family is. Looking in the relevant [latex directory](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/iwona/tex/latex/iwona), we could either pull the family name from the [sty file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/iwona/tex/latex/iwona/iwona.sty) or we could observe that there are four files defining families in the `T1` encoding: `t1iwona.fd`, `t1iwonal.fd`, `t1iwonac.fd` and `t1iwonalc.fd`. So the four family names are `iwona`, `iwonal`, `iwonac` and `iwonalc`. `iwona` is likely to be the standard family, with the others being variants. You could figure out the differences from the package file or (possibly) the documentation. [I'm guessing the `l` versions are 'light' and the `c` might be 'condensed' but these are just guesses.]

With these findings in place, we can use the fonts without loading the packages which will leave the default roman family undisturbed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=26pt]{geometry}% LaTeX reports that the headheight must be at least 25.something pt to accommodate the header
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% just for testing
\DeclareRobustCommand{\iwonafam}{%
        \fontencoding{T1}%
        \fontfamily{iwona}%
        \selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textiwona}{\iwonafam}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\baskervaldfam}{%
        \fontencoding{T1}%
        \fontfamily{ybv}%
        \selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbaskervald}{\baskervaldfam}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\begin{document}
  % set up the header after the start of the document so we get the right fonts and stuff automatically
  \newsavebox{\frightfulhead}
  \newlength{\frightfulwidth}
  \settowidth{\frightfulwidth}{\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont\Large\{ analysis first \}}% measure the required width
  \sbox{\frightfulhead}{% put the contents of the header in a box
    \parbox{\frightfulwidth}{% multiple lines so we'll use a \parbox with the width measured above
      \raggedleft% set everything flush right
      \textiwona{\Large {\{ analysis first \}}\\}% the curly brackets limit the scope of the font selection command
      \textbaskervald{\itshape solutions through science}}}% so this line returns to the default family i.e. baskervald
  \fancyhead[L]{\usebox{\frightfulhead}}% install the header

  \kant[1-2]% dummy text
\end{document}
```

[image: mix of 3 serifs...]

Comment: Thank you for your help. The change in fonts is because this is a logo. I have a version in graphics format, but did not like it. That's why I wanted to just select the different fonts, just build the logo in LaTeX. I know about using \ to force spaces. When I try to do something new, at least new to me, I go one step at a time. The plan was after I had the logo looking like I wanted it, font wise, then I would put it in a box or mini page to put in the header. As to loading the fonts, neither one is to be the default font, that will remain cm. I just needed them for the logo. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I'll still have a problem in implementing this the way I want it to appear.

Comment: Ok, I give up, how do I load the entire preamble so you can see exactly what I am trying to do?

Comment: @MikeFisher As I said before, post an MWE - not your entire preamble but a small, compilable document illustrating your problem. If you have a graphic version, posting that would also be helpful. Right now I don't have any idea what problem you are referring to. As far as I could tell, this was the way you wanted the logo to look except for the colours, of course. So I'm not at all clear what you want to change.

Comment: ok, the whole tex document is posted. I specifically want "solutions through science" in the header to be in italics. I can't add the graphic as I need ten points to post it. :-(

Comment: to cfr: thank you for being so patient with me

Comment: @MikeFisher But it is in italics in my solution. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: cfr: I think because you used baskervald as the default font, and I want to keep computer modern as the default font. I can always load baskervald as the default font, then change it back to computer modern in the body of the paper.

Comment: ok, I put the \usepackage{baskervald} back in, and it works. And it also looks like computer modern is still the default font. So I am happy. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MikeFisher Oh, I see. In that case, don't load `baskervald` either. See my update. (I don't know why you still get CM as default unless you later override the changes `baskervald` makes but it is better not to bother loading either font package.) Note that `\bf` etc. are deprecated, LaTeX 2.09 commands and ought not be used. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}` instead.